# Files not showing up for Directory.EnumerateFiles in debug mode in Monodevelop

Tags: c#, file-io, mono, monodevelop

I am using Monodevelop 2.8.2 with c# on windows 7. I am trying to write a function to get all files in a directory and all subdirectories.

When I do

```
string curdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(".", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} in {1}", file, curdir);
}
```

in debug mode, only the executable's name is found. However, if I run the executable directly through windows explorer, ie double clicking, all the files are shown (there are 9). Running monodevelop as administrator has no effect.

This works properly in visual studio, whats going on? I have tried building clean and verifying that the directories being checked are the same (if the executable were actually alone then the program wouldn't run, it needs 6 dll's!).

edit: removed free parameter

Comment: Where are you getting `dir` from?

Comment: @JaredPar oh, its just "." hardcoded

Comment: Wondering if you ever found any resolution for this? Do you recall if this was skipping subfolders?

Comment: @MrUnleaded i gave up on monodevelop, it is horrible

Answer (score 2):

The current working directory is `bin/Debug` when running in debug mode from the monodevelop IDE.

Unsurprisingly, it contains few files, outside the executable :)

So, either

- use another path instead of `"."`
- specify another working directory for debugging

**Edit** If the output directory actually *does* contain more files than listed, you might already *have* a specific working directory specified in the debug options of your project. You might want to check it, or just apply the above bullets unchanged :)

Comment: I have checked using GetCurrentDirectory() and the directory being checked in both cases is identical.

Comment: Mmm. In that case it must be down to a difference in runtime version. When you double click, you'll use MS.Net, Monodevelop targets Mono runtime by default. Could you try debugging with the .Net framework from Monodevelop (might require a recent version of Monodevelop)